# Dict of two non-header rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I need to keep without a header, and have the header on the first row. What would be the best way to create a `dict` of those two rows. For example:

```
df.loc[0:1]
```

Currently I would do something like:

```
dict(zip(df.loc[0].tolist(), df.loc[1].tolist()))
```

But was hoping that perhaps `pandas` had a simpler way to do that.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data? A [mcve], perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Use `header=None` in the `read_csv` function. Like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file,header = None)
```

Check the docs [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Then to create a `dict`:

```
df.iloc[:2].to_dict()
```